# How to determine how much of Linux meminfo 's cached value is available as free?

Tags: linux, memory

I am trying to figure out the amount of cache and buffers that is available and be counted as free memory(that is listed in free and /proc/meminfo). If I drop_caches I get some free but how does it do? Where can I find its source code?

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to get these values using some code ?
Regardless of that you could get all memory information from "/proc/meminfo".

On my machine, I could see:

```
MemTotal:        2051856 kB
MemFree:          522948 kB
Buffers:           74036 kB
Cached:           760480 kB
```

If you have to get it through some program then you can parse this file easily.
(Provided that you have access to proc filesystem)

Comment: well, that is no the question. the question is how much of cache is available as part of free. remember, linux doesnt release all of the caches only part of it so I need the formula. FYI : It is not memfree + buffers + cahced.